# Calling Sub resulting in Sub undefined error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to find a way to allow my tables to auto-expand while also preventing users from editing columns with formulas. Seems like it should be pretty straightforward without fancy coding given that it's a pretty common situation, but I digress...

I've found the following code online (apologies to the author as I don't remember where):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Sheets("Instructions").Range("autoExpand") Like "Disabled" Then Exit Sub

    Dim Tbl As ListObject, Off As Integer, ExitCode As Label
    Dim TblFirstRow As Long, TblFirstColumn As Integer
    Dim FirstRowAllowed As Long

    On Error GoTo ExitCode

    Off = 0: If Target.Row > 1 Then Off = -1
    Set Tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    TblFirstRow = Tbl.HeaderRowRange.Row
    TblFirstColumn = Tbl.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 1).Column
    OpenClipboard 0
    FirstRowAllowed = TblFirstRow

    If Target.Row >= FirstRowAllowed And Target.Row <= Tbl.ListRows.Count + TblFirstRow + 1 And _
        Target.Column <= Tbl.ListColumns.Count + TblFirstColumn And _
        Target.Cells.Offset(Off, 0).Locked = False Then
        Unprotect
        CloseClipboard
    Else
        GoTo ExitCode
    End If

    Exit Sub

    ExitCode:
        Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
                False, UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
                AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True, _
                AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
         CloseClipboard

End Sub
```

The code works great, but I'd like to use it on several worksheets within the same workbook, so I thought perhaps I could do:

IN WORKSHEET:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call table_expand
End Sub
```

IN MODULE:

```
Sub table_expand()

(pasted code from within the Sub above)

End Sub
```

This, however, does not work - I'm getting a

> "Sub not defined"

error. After some Googling it seems that the issue has to do with either missing or extra parentheses, but I'm not getting anything to work.

I can paste the code into all of the worksheets for the time being, but since I have about ten of them, basically I'm just trying to DRY it up a bit...

...which I should think is possible? As I'm sure is obvious I have almost zero experience with VBA, so many thanks for your help.

Comment: Use the `ThisWorkbook` code module, specifically the `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange` event, and then replace any references to `ActiveSheet` with `Sh` instead.  That way you only need the code in a single spot and it will work for all sheets in the workbook.

Comment: Might be by Catalin Bombea https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-worksheet-protection

Comment: Thanks @tigeravatar, but what if there are sheets that I don't want it to apply to?

Comment: @Shoelaced Just do an if statement or select case statement to exclude the sheets you don't want (you can use `Sh.Name`)

Comment: @tigeravatar Hmm, I'm getting a compile error. In the `ThisWorkbook` code module I have `Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)` and inside that I have `If Sh.Name <> "Sheet1" Or Sh.Name <> "Sheet2" Then` (with an `End If` at the end)... Am I missing something?

Comment: Don't have time to test, but how are you passing the relevant sheet and range to your `table_expand` macro?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but I was attempting to call the `table_expand` macro into each specific worksheet's code module. If you mean `(ByVal Target As Range)`, I tried adding that as `Sub table_expand(ByVal Target As Range)` but it didn't work.

Comment: I'll post something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you are not passing the relevant `Target` to your regular macro.  So it won't know what to work on.

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    myMacro Target
End Sub
```

And in the regular module:

```
Sub myMacro(Target As Range)
    MsgBox Target.Worksheet.Name & vbLf & Target.Address

End Sub
```

And in the regular macro, you'll need to change your references to worksheets to `Target.Sheet` or something similar, if you reference the worksheet where the event took place.

Note that, in VBA, `Call` is not required.

Also, as I realized after reading the comment by @chrisneilsen, instead of putting your event code on each worksheet, you can use Workbook event code instead.  Then you only need to enter it once.  For example:

Workbook code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Call myMacro(sh, Target)
End Sub
```

Regular Module:

```
Sub myMacro(sh As Worksheet, Target As Range)
    Dim Tbl As ListObject
    Set Tbl = sh.ListObjects(1)
    Stop

End Sub
```

Or you could just put all of your macro code into the workbook code; maintain a list of worksheets that you want this to occur on and add a test.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Sheets("Instructions").Range("autoExpand") Like "Disabled" Then Exit Sub

    Dim Tbl As ListObject, Off As Integer, ExitCode As Label
    Dim TblFirstRow As Long, TblFirstColumn As Integer
    Dim FirstRowAllowed As Long

    On Error GoTo ExitCode

    Off = 0: If Target.Row > 1 Then Off = -1
    Set Tbl = sh.ListObjects(1)
    TblFirstRow = Tbl.HeaderRowRange.Row
    TblFirstColumn = Tbl.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 1).Column
    OpenClipboard 0
    FirstRowAllowed = TblFirstRow

    If Target.Row >= FirstRowAllowed And Target.Row <= Tbl.ListRows.Count + TblFirstRow + 1 And _
        Target.Column <= Tbl.ListColumns.Count + TblFirstColumn And _
        Target.Cells.Offset(Off, 0).Locked = False Then
        Unprotect
       CloseClipboard
    Else
        GoTo ExitCode
    End If

    Exit Sub

ExitCode:
        Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
                False, UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
                AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True, _
                AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
         CloseClipboard
End Sub
```

Your code returns errors when run on my system, so I assume your environment is different since you wrote that it ran OK on your worksheet.

In particular:

- `OpenClipboard` is not defined
- `CloseClipboard` is not defined

and you will want to use the `Worksheet.Protect` method for that activity.

Comment: Hm, okay I've tried this and I'm getting an error. I have your first code in the worksheet module, and then in the regular module I have `Sub table_expand(Target As Range)` containing the code from my question. In it there's one instance of `ActiveSheet.ListObjects`, which I changed to `Target.Sheet.ListObjects`... it's giving me a "Sub not defined" error on `table_expand`.

Comment: You've butchered the event declaration.  It's missing `Sh`.  Create the event shell from the dropdown to ensure it is correct

Comment: @chrisneilsen That is appropriate with the `Workbook` event code.  I had entered it as Worksheet event code as the OP had indicated he wanted to do that.  But I like your idea and will edit my response.

Comment: @shoelaced Target.Sheet is wrong, should be Target.Worksheet  and actually should be Sh once you fix the event.  And why are you persisting with rable_expand?  Put the code in the event!

Comment: @Shoelaced `ListObjects` is not a property of `Target.Sheet`.  It is a property of `Target.Worksheet`.  But there are other issues with your code.

Comment: @chrisneilsen, I'm sorry - I don't know what rable_expand means. Again I have little experience with this.

Comment: @Shoelaced `table_expand` is the VBA Macro YOU indicated YOU were writing in your original post

Comment: Ah, then I was confused because he misspelled it. Trying the new solution now.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Genius, got it working! Thanks so much. I realized I did have the clipboard functions defined elsewhere, so removing those helped, and then the only thing I had to change was to use `Sh.Protect` (and `Sh.Unprotect`) instead of `Worksheet.Protect`. Thanks again.